# How to convert the java String to different languages

Tags: java, string, utf-8, localization

Currently I am writing some text to pdf. based on the user locale, the language must be changed(ex: spanish, chineese, german).

Is there any API for this conversion? and Better approach?

Comment: you need to translate the strings and use a mechanism like a property file to get strings based on locale

Comment: You want to translate text? Or just change the locale? The latter is easy. The former, not so much.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Yes, I want to convert the text.

Comment: If it is static text I would suggest using properties files and reading from the correct file based on locale

Comment: @orangegoat, *ECHO echo echo echo..*

Comment: For dynamic text, you are out of luck. The state of the art (AFAIK) in this is Google Translate, and just look at the results... they are pretty impressive for programmatic conversion but not acceptable as is as real translations presented to users.

Answer (score 1):

You would have a default key for each String you need translated:

```
title=The StackOverflow
content=The StackOverflow is an interesting site.
```

This would be stored in text_EN.properties for the EN locale.

For each other language, you would have text_.properties. Example text_FR.properties:

```
title=Le StackOverflow
content=Le StackOverflow est un site interessant.
```

(title, content, and other keys should are your keys and should be the same in all your properties files, since that is how you access them.)

When you are about to write the text to the pdf, you would acquire each value from the relevant properties file, based on the locale/language you need.

There are different templating languages you can use for this if you don't want to do it yourself. `Thymeleaf` comes to mind, but I think there is also `Velocity`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ResourceBundles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html). You can find many tutorials via Google, for instance [this one](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html).