# Format string with default language in android

Tags: java, android, string-formatting, string.format

I have a String number like

```
 String a="2016";
```

which I want to show it in android default language characters.
for example, if my default language was Persian or Farsi my string must be

a=[image: 2016]
can anyone help me about that?

Comment: put a to corresponding to language string file, it's tedious but work

Comment: yes but I wanna easier way

Comment: Please visit the link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14717367/how-to-convert-the-java-string-to-different-languages]

Comment: yes i can see but i wanna easier way like below answer but something works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this worked for me

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.forLanguageTag("ar"));
Log.i("123", nf.format(123));
```

Comment: not working for me, I try both String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"%s",a) and String.format(new Locale("fa"),"%s",a)